# How to find a low-challenge, low-variety job when coming from a highly educated background?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, education, stress

I am a university graduate with a BSc and an MA. I am currently working for a (very) large financial company as a java developer who effectively spends most his time doing everything else IT related. I'm effectively sent on every possibly IT errand; whether it is upgrading existing systems or designing new ones.

Some people would appreciate the variety and challenge, but I experience it as extremely stressful. I do all this for near-minimum wage, and have decided I can happily live off that.

Asking around, though, it seems that with my educated background getting a 'monotonous' or 'routine' job would be nearly impossible within the company. Especially data entry would be an impossibility.
At the same time, when going to another company on interview one of the questions I struggle with is "what new challenges are you looking for?", as I am explicitly trying to avoid challenges, and mostly want to just provide menial labour.

Is there a viable way to get a low-challenge, low-variety job when relatively highly educated?

Comment: Why are you looking for a job in a field like IT-services if you don't want challenge? If you're looking for monotony, you should probably try a different field alltogether.

Comment: It sounds like you aren't looking for monotony so much as a slower paced or more focused role. I'm assuming you _like_ challenging tasks--it's just that you're pulled in different directions and spread out too thin.

Comment: @RobertDundon - your comment seems to be flying in the face of what the OP has stated .. be careful about making too many assumptions.

Comment: I have to say, I don't know that I've ever heard anyone ask a question along these lines before. It's somewhat .. depressing. But if that's what you want you can always work in the local supermarket! I hear shelving produce isn't very challenging.

Comment: @AndreiROM Just trying to get in between the lines to clarify the question. Based on the OP's description of being pulled on different projects, I'm thinking fragmentation of time and impending burnout.

Weckar E: Did you volunteer for most of those IT projects?

Comment: I think the qualification of a "challenge" in the IT sphere may be the real problem for me. I also think it is worth mentioning why I am in the field was a matter of affinity, not qualification - as my degrees are in general applied sciences and theatre production. I stuck to those moreso for the love of the academic environment than the job prospects.
I also think I'm a great example that being qualified to do something does not mean you want to do it.

Comment: Have you thought about moving to help desk roles? Especially in large corporations, these can basically turn into coaching users to reboot and put paper in their printer

Comment: If you are willing to work for near-minimum wage then you have lot of options for menial labor.  You will be over qualified.  You just have to convince them you are interested in the job.   See the movie American Beauty.  Careful what you ask for.

Comment: I hope more people are like you. I'm tired of people trying to be superman and failing every project they can.

Comment: @Erik you are very wrong, if someone is competente at some language or skill there are no much of "challenge" on it. Depends much of project assigned.

Comment: Programming skills + desire for monotony makes me think you should consider being an SDET.  It's a job most developers avoid because testing is monotonous.

Comment: Recommended reading: "*[how to explain why I want a lower-level, lower-responsibility job](http://www.askamanager.org/2013/06/how-to-explain-why-i-want-a-lower-level-lower-responsibility-job.html)*" /// "*[how important is job satisfaction, really?](http://www.askamanager.org/2016/04/how-important-is-job-satisfaction-really.html)*" /// "*[I hate work, all of it, with a passion](http://www.askamanager.org/2015/03/i-hate-work-all-of-it-with-a-passion.html)*"

Comment: I'm curious: why did you bother to get all this education if all you want is data entry?

Comment: @Lilienthal great reading, honestly :)

Comment: @PM 77-1 as said, I enjoy the academic environment (although research is far too much of an independent process for that to be a viable career for me).

Comment: @agentroadkill in the company I am currently at it's already been made plenty clear to me that such isn't an option. For a future employer certainly worth considering.

Comment: "Is there a viable way to get a low-challenge, low-variety job when relatively highly educated?" Yes, you have to be willing to delete most of your resume. Java developer, take that out. IT, take that out. For your degrees, omit them, and just say that you didn't graduate when asked about it. Then apply for a package handler job at the post office, UPS, or FedEx. Or may be, become a night security guard, or an attendant at a gas station, or a landscaper. Those jobs are out there. It's just that you'll never get them if they're afraid of losing you after only one week of work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your goal is monotony and you are ok with making around or near minimum wage, I would recommend changing industries.

IT as a field in general has expectations which probably will not be agreeable to you long term.

My recommendation for finding what you want to do is to find the types of things you do and find jobs related to them. For example, I have a cousin who has done seasonal work for years - he works in some of the most beautiful locations in our country, doesn't make much money, but gets to spend all his time outdoors in beautiful country.

I actually have dreamed of doing this - basically quitting my software engineering career and finding a career that has me outdoors in nature all the time.

Oftentimes though working for minimum wage level jobs may be more stressful as you will deal with worse managers and worse coworkers. This is why I would look for more a "specialty" minimum wage level job.

Last, you can always take things off your resume - if you apply for a manual data entry job, consider taking your degree(s) off your resume if you feel they are making you overqualified.

Comment: I'm generally fearful for leaving things off my resume for having to explain gaps. Still, "Do what you love" is generally great advice.

Comment: @WeckarE. don't forget that nearly _every_ industry has some amount of menial/mundane work associated with it. Entertainment industries have a lot of potential here - if you like skiing, living in Colorado (if you are in the USA). Etc.  If your goal is to do this type of work there will nearly always be options.

Comment: I'm sorry for not understanding, but how is skiing a job? And while it is true nearly every industry has work of this type, I would argue my greatest enemy is automation...

Comment: @WeckarE. I mean in ski towns there are a lot of people who do manual labor types of jobs at resorts, etc. If you loved skiing you could work for a ski resort or lodge and be able to ski often while still making your money.

Answer (score 5):

**Certainly.**

There are *tons* of programming and IT jobs that are doing the same basic thing day in and day out. Personally, I find most QA work to be that sort of thing, though the crunches near release time might not be what you consider low stress. Some programming jobs are just standing up basic websites for small businesses. Again, not terribly challenging or stressful.

But the thing to realize is that a low stress work environment is less about the work and more about the company culture. So before derailing your career too severely, I would recommend simply changing your approach. It's not that you're looking for monotonous work, but that you're looking for a low stress environment since you know that helps you succeed. It's not that you're looking for routine work, but that you work best in an environment with fewer unknowns.

As an employee, you need to be a little picky during your job search - for culture as well as work/salary/title. And you'll need to be able to do a little salesmanship to convince the company that a laid back sort of environment is best for you, and will allow you to best help them.

Comment: Although I do not appreciate the assumptions on what I am 'actually' looking for, you raise a few fair points. My main issue in job hunts thus far is that "laid-back" and "stable"/"structured" usually do not pop up in the same ads.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about moving up in your career and don't want to do this type of work, why are you stressed? Are you being asked to do things you don't feel capable of or are under time constraints?

Stop responding to a variety of tasks. Start telling people you don't know how to do those things. You don't care about money, so losing a job shouldn't be a problem.

If you're over-qualified, stop putting your education on your resume. Apply for a job in data entry atanother company. Many people leave out skills, education, certification and experience it if is not relevant to the job. Even in your current position, you don't have to mention everything you do. Tell them your current title doesn't really fit the job. It sounds like you will do a good job and not look for something more challenging, so you'd be a good fit.

Comment: Without sounding overly arrogant, I think the reason I work the way I do is because I'm too 'nice'. I find it very hard to refuse helping people when asked.
Are employment/education gaps really not that big a deal anymore?

Comment: You don't have to leave a gap. You can say you worked at a company but don't list everything you did. I realize the title can be misleading. Obviously if you were a programmer, you did some programming, but you can indicate you spent most of your time doing other things that you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

In general you're in the wrong company. Usually the bigger the company, the less of this sort of work you will encounter.

So look for a big company with a large well established IT team. These normally have more set roles. And there are plenty of them out there. Govt is also a good option, plenty of Govt IT employees rarely do anything different and quite often they're overstaffed and just sit around most of the time.

Comment: My current job is actually Govt, in a sense. Which frankly makes all the cobbled together messes of applications no more fun to work with.

Comment: Can't you just mess around and make excuses for why stuff hasn't been done until they assign it to someone else or bring in a contractor? That's what they seem to do over here... it's a good living for us contractors. I've seen govt principal IT with 10 years experience where their whole experience was messing around and making excuses.

Answer (score 1):

If there's too much stress and you're working for near minimum wage, I might suggest working part time for a higher rate. You'll be at work less, which would help with the stress levels, and won't always be available to be 'that guy' to run to when there's an IT issue. It would also be easier to find a 'monotonous' job, with minimal task variety, since they aren't expecting to keep you busy for 40 hours a week.

In addition, as you mentioned in some of the comments, maybe you can have more time to work on Theater things, if t

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a monotonous IT related job you should consider becoming a professional software tester.

You need intense focus, sharp memory and pattern recognition as a software tester and you'll need to be able to do that over and over.

And your job is incredibly important since more and more companies see the value of software testing.

Comment: Where I live you could pay 3 testers at minimum wage for the same salary of a highly educated person.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt, what kind of an idiot would hire minimum wage testers? Yes testers generally are lower paid in terms of IT people but they should be well above minimum wage.

Comment: @HLGEM I guess it depends on the industry, but EA did not have any issue hiring testers at _very_ low wages.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt game dev is an outlier as far as testing goes, since it's trivially easy to get people to not only test (poorly) for free, but even to pay you to test your game.

Comment: Knowing some people in game testing, it is anything but a low-pressure environment!